# bash out processes from a range

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to out the number of working processes identifiers lying in specific range. For example, I have three processes with PIDs: 125, 200, 450. Then I need a command like(pseudo-code) -

> top -r 100-300

I want to see in output

> 2

It is a sum of two processes with PIDs 125 and 200.
I cannot understand, how I can do this with help of 'ps' and 'top' commands. Maybe there are any other commands? Or my job can be done with these commands?

Thanks!

Comment: `ps ax|grep -E '(125|200)'|wc -l`, perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk` like this:

```
ps | awk '($1>=lo)&&($1<=hi){n++}END{print n}'
```

Replace `lo` with your lower limit (100) and `hi` with your upper limit (300).

Or you may get away with this if your range is small enough:

```
ps -h -p {100..300} | wc -l
```